# Get always 0 value in a simple mathematical calc

Tags: java, math

I'm testing an app that use this method

```
public double range(double[] myArray1, double[] myArray2, double[] myArray3) {
    int count=myArray1.length;

    double dfw = (3 * count) - 3;
    double msw = totalval / dfw;
    double critical = (2 / count) * (msw / 2);

    double range = Math.sqrt(critical);
    double crange = 3.95* range;

    return critical;
}
```

I have tried to print all values for an input of 3 arrays all with length 4;

```
dfw=9
msw=341.6388888888889
critical=0;
range=0;
crange=0;
```

All values are calculated correctly but when the execution reach `critical`, the values aren't calculated.

How is this thing possible? Why `critical` results always 0 causing a wrong output?

Comment: Also: `3,95* range` the `,` is a typo, right? Should be `.`

Comment: @laalto was 3.95 is a trascription error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `(2 / count)` is an `Integer` operation, which will return `0` if `count > 2`.

To change it to a floating point operation, you can use a floating point literal, like this:

```
double critical = (2.0 / count) * (msw / 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are performing integer math. `int myvalue = 1/2` will give you `myvalue = 0;`

you can  perform a cast

```
double critical = (2.0 / (double)count) * (msw / 2.0);
```

to promote `count` from `int` to `double`